# Bluetooth device pop-up

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth, airplay

I am struggling to find out how can I add a button in my React-Native App which triggers the following native pop up for connecting Bluetooth devices on iOS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMl2s.png

I have tested [react-native-airplay-ios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-airplay-ios) but there seems to be something wrong with the library.

Is there any preexisting and working library available?

Comment: You need to show an [`AVRoutePickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avroutepickerview)